# Qt - Expand QTreeView on single click?

Tags: c++, qt, mobile, qt4

While double-clicking the text of a QTreeView expands the children, a single-click does not.  The icon defined in the CSS (and placed to left of text) expands the children on a single-click, though.  How do I make it so a single-click (or touch event) of the text will expand the children?

```
    bookTreeView->setModel(standardModel);
    bookTreeView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    bookTreeView->setWordWrap(true);
    bookTreeView->sizeHint();
    //bookTreeView->mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent());
    bookTreeView->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideNone);
    bookTreeView->setExpandsOnDoubleClick(true);
    bookTreeView->setUniformRowHeights(true);
    bookTreeView->setHeaderHidden(true);
    bookTreeView->setStyleSheet("QTreeView { font-size: 27px; show-decoration-selected: 0; } QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item { border-image: none; } QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item { border-image: none; } QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item { border-image: none;} QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed, QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings { border-image: none; image: url(':images/images/right_arrow.png'); } QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings, QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  { border-image: none; image: url(':images/images/down_arrow.png'); } ");
```

Comment: Just a note, this is usually undesired behavior. Being able to select a view without having it being expanded is generally preferred

Comment: i'm not sure why i see it being undesirable for a mobile application - i don't want all the children expanded on a single-click, just the ones relating to the parent i clicked.  double clicking seems extraneous for a mobile app!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
QObject::connect(
    tree, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)), 
    tree, SLOT(expand(const QModelIndex &))
);
```

The `clicked`signal might not do what you want. You can also have a look at the `currentChanged` signal, which might be what you want. I've never used Qt in a mobile context :)

Comment: this is pretty close!  when i single-click a parent, it expands.  when i single-click another parent though, it runs through my custom slot that handles the children clicks and doesn't display the children.  i'll have a go at it.  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Same **Grund** answer, but I add close on the click if it already open.

```
QObject::connect(
    tree, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)), 
    this, SLOT(expandItem(const QModelIndex &))
);

void MainWindow::expandItem(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    tree->isExpanded(index)? tree->collapse(index) : tree->expand(index);
}
```

in mainwindow.h:

```
private slots:
void expandItem(const QModelIndex &index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to turn off double click expansion?

```
bookTreeView->setExpandsOnDoubleClick(false);
```

Comment: yea, just turns off double-click expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
ui.tree_view->setExpandsOnDoubleClick(false);
QObject::connect(ui.tree_view, &QTreeView::clicked, [this]() {
    if (ui.tree_view->isExpanded(ui.tree_view->currentIndex())) {
        ui.tree_view->collapse(ui.tree_view->currentIndex());
    }else{
        ui.tree_view->expand(ui.tree_view->currentIndex());
    }
});
```

**Tested on the Visual Studio version of Qt.**
An alternate method that opens and closes on a single click.
This method has no extra function required as it uses a lambda.
Place this in your constructor to run.
note: I set expands on double click to false because logically when one click expands, two clicks will undo the expand that the first one did.
That option makes the flow smoother and more consistent.